# Saving text box inputs in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, visual-studio

I want to be able to put some text into a text box but then have that text get copied over to an excel document.

This is a program for a confrence where people will be signing in with names, emails, and addresses. I just don't know how to get it to be able to put that data into an excel document.

Comment: ...what have you tried? You should post your code or people will start downvoting your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply export raw text-based data, then Excel does not require XLSX files. Instead you could export it as a CSV file (Comma-Separated Values). For each person, write a single line of information, separating each field (name, email etc) with a comma.

Assuming you actually mean VB.NET instead of VBA, refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w(v=vs.110).aspx for how to write the CSV file.

And by "***a*** textbox", I can only assume that you input one person's data at a time, and clear it before entering another person's details. A better way would be to have separate textboxes for each field, and a "Submit" button that adds a line to the list and also clears the textboxes.